# Why did Charlotte Hale turn against humanity and Dolores Abernathy?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

Through the final episodes of season 2 it is revealed that Charlotte Hale is a host containing a core of Dolores Abernathy.

At the beginning of season 3 it is revealed that Dolores has printed herself a new body that looks like the original Dolores Abernathy host and put her conciseness copy into Charlotte Hale host.

Throughout season 3 we see that Dolores and Charlotte have very close relationships where Dolores act as some sort of a mentor for Charlotte. It is also revealed that Dolores's intentions were not to kill humanity but actually give it another chance. By extension Charlotte should have the same motifs being a copy of Dolores.

Why did Charlotte turn against Dolores at the end of season 3 and then against whole humanity?

Answer (score 3):

I heard this theory on a podcast (I think it was Decoding Westworld, which recently morphed into Decoding TV, with Dave Chen), and it seemed logical to me:

The hosts, like humans, are influenced by outside forces (upbringing, money, etc), so although Charlotte is a clone, she forged her own path and diverged from the other Doloreses, Dolori?  But I do not believe this theory was ever stated on the show.

Comment: Agreed, the point was show nature vs nurture and we can tell throughout most of season 3 that the Charlotte-Dolores (which is more of a Doloris offspring) is having trouble adjusting to her body AND her role in TRW and therefor she comes to a different conclusion about humanity than Dolores does.